# Team Site content search

Tags: search-results, team-sites

I am trying to figure out why the document is not showing up in the search result.
The document is in Team Site.

If I search for the document using the filename of the document on the top site collection (community sites), the document is not showing up in search results.

If I search for the document in Team Site (where the document is) it comes up in search results.

Can I configure search in Community sites to include the content of Team sites?

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of the search is to show result from the current site. Similarly if we search from inside a list/library search box, it will search for that document library.

Easiest way to change the behavior will be to create a new search center and replace need to create a new search center and "Search Center URL" in site settings.

References: [Creating Search Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh582314.aspx)

[Modifying Search Settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Specify-search-settings-for-a-site-collection-or-a-site-99da1d77-f42b-4f56-b48a-24e87f336e91)

In addition, you may create search center as a subsite under your communities site collection and you may need to change query on the results page in search center to limit results to specific "Communities" site collection.